# Are same symbols in different shared libs looked up starting from the root of the symbol namespace always again?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, elf

From what I have gathered, symbol name lookup for a default-visibility symbol of a shared library iterates through the shared library dependency tree in breath-first order, with the executable program being the root of this search tree. All libraries that are linked by one DT_NEEDED list are at the same level of this tree.

Thus, when a symbol "foo" is looked up, it seems to me that its lookup is deterministically always bound to the same library or executable at runtime. Does the dynamic linker exploit this and has a "global symbol table" of sorts (perhaps associated with the link-map list), that knows what symbol belongs to what shared library once a symbol was first looked up, and takes the address of the symbol out of that libraries' GOT when the symbol is looked up by a different shared library a second time? Or will the symbol always be looked up as if this was its first lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thus, when a symbol "foo" is looked up, it seems to me that its lookup is deterministically always bound to the same library or executable at runtime.

This view is *way* oversimplified. There are many complications, such as presence of `DT_SYMBOLIC` on the referencing DSO, presence of `RTLD_LOCAL` when defining DSO is loaded (if it's not linked in directly), and I am sure some other complications I am not remembering at the moment.

> Does the dynamic linker exploit this and has a "global symbol table" of sorts

GLIBC loader does not do that.

> Or will the symbol always be looked up as if this was its first lookup?

Yes. You can observe this with `LD_DEBUG=symbols,bindings ./a.out`

Comment: Thanks for answering. What is your take on this; would it improve performance, trading space for speed in the majority of cases?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes: it could drastically improve performance under certain conditions. For example, Google carries a local GLIBC patch to achieve this. Some details: https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2013-02/msg00040.html